# Polymer and external node.js Libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, polymer, bower

I am working with Polymer 1.0 and now it's time to add an external .JS library.
The library I want to add is called SuperAgent and it is a Node.js module capable to provide powerful APIs for XMLHttpRequests. It is also suggested by Polymer's team.

**Step 01 - Add bower module**

```
$ bower install --save superagent
```

**Step 02 - Add `<script>` reference**

```
<!-- SuperAgent -->
<script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   src="/bower_components/superagent/lib/client.js"></script>
```

Now I get an error in Chrome saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If I inspect the client.js file, it has these statements at the beginning, which are the cause of my error:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var Emitter = require('emitter');
var reduce = require('reduce');
```

Now, my project is done using **exclusively** bower, what do I need to do in order to make "require" understandable by my Polymer app? Is there a bower component + script that do that?

Comment: From SuperAgent website: "Works with browserify and should work with webpack". Add one of those to your project's pipeline. `require` does not work in clientside, you need one of those tools to transform SuperAgent's code into something deployable.

Comment: Is there any reason to choose one "browserify" or the other "webpack"?

Comment: Webpack is the current cool kid.  http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack_compared/

Comment: Ok @krl I will have a look at webkit. Unfortunately Polymer 1.0 doesn't have any reference on how to work with external bower coponents

Comment: Working with external components is not Polymer specific feature.  The issue is that superagent uses modules via `require` which is native Node.js module format, but supported by browsers.  That's why you need Browserify ot Webpack to make it work in the browser.  Alternatively you can you use browser only HTTP library or even built-in Fetch API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API (not supported by IE)

Comment: @krl I am aware of those, I am an AngularJS dev but I never worked with Node.js modules so for me the "require" keyword is something new. I don't understand why Polymer team kindly suggest to use SUperAgent, but I think I will use Browserify, Webpack documentation is just impossible to read

Comment: I decided to use jQuery. It has everything needed to make any kind of complex ajax call and it integrates perfectly into Polymer. I think they push to use SuperAgent because their entire backend in Node.js so they assume that everybody will have a Node.js backend if working on a Polymer app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SuperAgent before and I am familiar with Polymer (but haven't used it much)

SuperAgent is a server side nodeJS npm package used to stand up a server for running a batch of unit tests and it is then shut down.

Polymer is a client side tool used to make the full power of the shadow DOM available now.

How the 2 work together I have no idea but the require statements used by SuperAgent are nodeJS require statements made to require other modules. The reason your browser doesn't understand require is because browsers don't yet understand modularity (although they will do soon with ES6 modules on the way in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's the point, SuperAgent is a node.js script while Polymer team "sell it" as a Client side framework for complex XMLHttpReqeusts.